# App Engine, WordPress and File Limites 10.000

Tags: wordpress, limit, gcloud

Any solution for allowing more than 10.000 files per application? We are in the progress of moving all our WordPress sites to the App Engine and some of them have more than 10.000 files.

We pay on average about $400 per month on Gcloud and another $300 per month on Gapps but I don't see any paid option to increase this level or see a final documented solution to this..

Comment: I have found that there is a feature request to increase the limit, you can track it b.corp.google.com/issues/136493206

Comment: I have it logged here as well so it might have gone down the chain a bit https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180151795

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Cloud App Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted) you can request a quota increase if you have a silver, gold or platinum support package.

> Is your app exceeding the default limits? If you need a higher mail quota, you can use SendGrid to send email. For any other quota increase, if you have Silver, Gold, or Platinum support package, you can contact your support representative to request higher throughput limits.

Comment: Yeah exactly, so instead of paying for the increase you have to pay for an additional support package in order to ask support for an increase. That's definitely not a great solution right

Comment: I agree. It would properly be a better solution to see if something can be done about the number of files you have. 10000+ is a staggering amount

Comment: WordPress out of the box is already 2500 files without any plugins or themes etc.